# File truncated because of accents

Tags: java, jsf-2, download

I have an application generating sql files, my problem is when I try to download the file and there is an accent in the request I get the following result:

```
delete from gfe_param_fa where parfa_ident=9 and parfa_code_doc='ANNEXEC17' and parfa_libelle_doc='Dde certificat d''hérédité' and parfa_interaction='NON' and parfa_identifiant='POLICE' and parfa_remise='LETTRE' and parfa_application='ANNEXE_CO' and nvl(parfa_tri1,'NULL') = 'NULL' and nvl(parfa_tri2,'NULL') = 'NULL' and nvl(parfa_tri3,'NULL') = 'NULL' and parfa_archivage='OUI' and parfa_chemise='ANNEXE_GESTION' and parfa_type_appli_au='CL' and parfa_application_cl='ANNEXE_CO' and nvl(parfa_application_au,'NULL') = 'NUL
```

instead of

```
delete from gfe_param_fa where parfa_ident=9 and parfa_code_doc='ANNEXEC17' and parfa_libelle_doc='Dde certificat d''hérédité' and parfa_interaction='NON' and parfa_identifiant='POLICE' and parfa_remise='LETTRE' and parfa_application='ANNEXE_CO' and nvl(parfa_tri1,'NULL') = 'NULL' and nvl(parfa_tri2,'NULL') = 'NULL' and nvl(parfa_tri3,'NULL') = 'NULL' and parfa_archivage='OUI' and parfa_chemise='ANNEXE_GESTION' and parfa_type_appli_au='CL' and parfa_application_cl='ANNEXE_CO' and nvl(parfa_application_au,'NULL') = 'NULL';
```

I've isolated the cause of the problem to the accents; it doesn't happen whenever there is no accent in the request.

Here's my download function:

```
public void download(String request) throws IOException {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        input = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                request.getBytes()), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        ec.responseReset();
        ec.setResponseContentType("application/sql");
        ec.setResponseContentLength(request.length());
        ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=\"" + "update.sql" + "\"");
        ec.setResponseHeader("Refresh", "1; url = main.xhtml");
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(ec.getResponseOutputStream(),
                DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        output.flush();
    } finally {
        close(output);
        close(input);
    }
    fc.responseComplete();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

```
ec.setResponseContentLength(request.length())
```

and this

```
input = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
            request.getBytes()), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

together those lines make the bug.

How many bytes does the second line give you, is it equal to the number of characters in the string? Nope.  "request.getBytes()" is returning bytes for the string using the default encoding, which is platform dependent.  (it will change with OS/JVM/language, etc).  On the other hand, request.length() will always be the same, for a given string.

Instead you, want:

```
 // explicit character encoding, so it never changes
byte[] requestBytes = request.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Then use that byte array to initialize your stream **and** to determine the content length.